# How to update mu-plugin

Tags: plugins, updates, mu-plugins

I'm managing a wordpress site that was developed by another party, and they put a bunch of plugins in the mu-plugins folder. These plugins can't be updated via the default interface of WordPress, and must be updated manually.
I can't find any details on how to correctly update these plugins. Is it just a matter of replacing the current files with the updated version of the plugin?

An additional question: can I just transfer these plugins to the plugins folder, or would there be a risk of the plugin/site breaking? Assuming all these plugins are correctly programmed and available in the WP plugins directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please check this out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

In most cases mu plugins consist of a singular php file in that directory. In that case you could just replace the file. In any case, there is neither a process for installation nor uninstallation, you simply drop files in that dir or delete them from it.

It's as it is always with updates: Back the directory up, replace the plugin files one by one and check if everything's still working as expected.

Never used the mu-plugins dir to store regular plugins. As e.g. activation hooks don't fire in there, not every plugin is suitable to be put there. IF a regular plugin was put there, I would try to remove it (again, backup!) and install the latest version as you would any other.

Comment: That's what I expected. Thanks for the information, I'll try and remove these plugins from the mu-plugins dir and reinstall them in the regular plugins.